# input focus icon change

Tags: android, webview

I made a website and made an application by using a `webview` of android studio.
It's a difficult icon to describe, so I'll show you the image.

[image]

(I'm sorry to have a lack of reputation.)

I want to change the color and shape of the displayed icon.
Do I need to use a JAVA language? Or should I use CSS?
Please advise.

Comment: Jeong Is it load from your web page or Is this a view in your xml?

Comment: webview is A View that displays web pages. This class is the basis upon which you can roll your own web browser or simply display some online content within your Activity. So if you need to change that content can web view help iT?

Comment: Thank you very much for your sincere reply. Then, which class should I revise at webview?

Comment: Jeong The view with that hello thing in your page you can change it as you want